# Check if any pandas dataframe column values are within another pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have df1 with messy Company names:

```
     messyCompany        
0    google123xyz              
1     amazon12345
2       amzn12345
3   mcdonalds inc      
4  healthtech ltd
```

And df2 with clean Company names and corresponding keywords:

```
     cleanCompany  keywords        
0          Amazon    amazon           
1          Amazon      amzn
```

I want to check if the messyCompany in df1 contains any of the keyword values from df2, if so bring in clean Company name. For example:

```
     messyCompany     cleanCompany  
0    google123xyz              
1     amazon12345           Amazon
2       amzn12345           Amazon
3   mcdonalds inc      
4  healthtech ltd
```

I first tried using two for loops; one to loop through messyCompany names and for each value loop through keywords. But that was extremely slow.

Then I tried replacing one for loop with apply:

```
def search(x):
   for i in range(df2.shape[0]):
      if df2['keywords'] in df1['messyCompany']:
         return df2['cleanCompany']

df1['cleanCompany'] = df1.apply(lambda x: search(x), axis=1)
```

This was faster but still slow overall(the actual df's have thousands of rows). I tried using an apply nested in another apply but this was slower. I've been reading a lot how to optimize pandas(apply, vectorization, chunking, etc...), but I can't seem to find best method for optimizing the double loop needed. Is there a best practice for this type of double loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `str.extract` instead and `map` the results:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'messyCompany': {0: 'google123xyz', 1: 'amazon12345', 2: 'amzn12345', 3: 'mcdonalds inc', 4: 'healthtech ltd'}})
ref = pd.DataFrame({'cleanCompany': {0: 'Amazon', 1: 'Amazon'}, 'keywords': {0: 'amazon', 1: 'amzn'}})

df["found"] = (df["messyCompany"].str.extract("("+"|".join(ref["keywords"])+")", expand=False)
                 .map(ref.set_index("keywords")["cleanCompany"]))

print (df)

     messyCompany   found
0    google123xyz     NaN
1     amazon12345  Amazon
2       amzn12345  Amazon
3   mcdonalds inc     NaN
4  healthtech ltd     NaN
```

Comment: thanks! I'm getting this error now: `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 10`  any idea what that could be?

Comment: Wild guess is you have a `*` in one of the values of your `keywords` column.

Comment: Yep that was it! haha thanks so much! Is there a way to do the same search but only if the company name STARTS WITH keyword instead of CONTAINS?

Comment: Use `"^("+"|".join(ref["keywords"])+")"` as the pattern instead.